# C# scripting interface

Tags: c#, scripting

I'm aware this has been asked a lot o times. However, I'm having a small dilemma. I'm currently developing a server for a game my friend is developing. The objects in it are executed through scripts (I didn't want to "hardcore" them), so I used the CodeDomProvider and made an abstract class that includes all the necessary methods. However, I hate having to import all the needed stuff every time and wanted to ask if there's a different approach (that's not C#).

I really like Lua, however the interface for Lua is old (2008). I have found NLua, though, what do you think about it? Is there another interface for Lua that's updated, or, is there another scripting language and interface you'd recommend and how to use them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use:

- [LuaInterface](http://luaforge.net/projects/luainterface/)

How about *Python*? It can be easily integrated with C# and it's and object-oriented programming language.

- [Python for .NET](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html#installation)

However, scripting languages offer you the simplest syntax.

Comment: LuaInterface is very old and outdated. Isn't there a newer interface for Lua?

Comment: Here you can find some .NET implementations of Lua. [link](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaImplementations)

Comment: You can use [NLua](https://github.com/nlua/nlua), is a fork of LuaInterface is currently maintained and recommended even by the LuaInterface original [author](https://code.google.com/p/luainterface/).